# Powershell Function import multiple CSVs into Excel workbook

Tags: arrays, excel, function, powershell, csv

Ok, time to start this question over.  I found the following script http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/09/copy-csv-columns-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-by-using-powershell.aspx

My question is how would I get powershell to loop that script for any number of CSV files.  The speed of the script is not important.  I've received some answers of which, in some way, have their problems.  Using the Technet script provides the correct output.

I have come up with this but am having a tough time getting the code to loop through multiple CSV files.

```psh
Function Excel-Stuff {
[cmdletBinding()]
Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string]$junk)
$excel.cells.item(1,1) = "Server"
$excel.cells.item(1,2) = "Rack"
$excel.cells.item(1,3) = "Environment"
$excel.cells.item(1,4) = "RebootTime"
$excel.cells.item(1,5) = "Schedule"
$i = 2
$processes = Import-Csv 'C:\Monday.csv'
foreach ($process in $processes){
 $excel.cells.item($i,1) = $process.Server
 $excel.cells.item($i,2) = $process.Rack
 $excel.cells.item($i,3) = $process.Environment
 $excel.cells.item($i,4) = $process.RebootTime
 $excel.cells.item($i,5) = $process.Schedule
 $i++
} #end foreach process
$autofit = $Global:worksheet.UsedRange
$autofit.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
}#End Function.
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.add(1)
$Global:worksheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1)
$Global:worksheet.Name='Monday'
Excel-Stuff
$Excel.visible = $True
```

Comment: This approach is slow. Can't you open the CSVs directly in Excel and copy the sheets to a new workbook? As for the error you're getting: worksheet objects don't have a `Worksheets` property (they don't contain other worksheets).

Comment: I'll admit I'm just throwing darts at code examples trying to come up with something workable.  I haven't found sample code that opens any number of CSVs then moves them into Excel and renames the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's not do this the hard way. Copy/paste is your friend, and you can do it easily here.

You have Monday-Friday tabs, and I assume 7 CSV files. Loop this thing 7 times, and in each loop Create a tab, name it, then copy the entire CSV, convert it to a tab delimited CSV, and pipe it to CLIP.exe. Then just select A1 on the current sheet and paste. Start the next loop with the next CSV file.

```psh
$path = "c:\tmp\mytest.xlsx"
$day = @("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $false
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.add(1)

$day | %{
 $processes = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Scripts\work\$_.csv"
 $worksheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.add()
 $processes | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Clip.exe
 $worksheet.select()
 $worksheet.Name = $_
 [void]$Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1").Select()
 [void]$Excel.ActiveCell.PasteSpecial()
 [void]$worksheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
}

#Clean up extra sheets
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$workbook.Worksheets|?{$day -notcontains $_.name}|%{$_.Delete()}
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $true

[void]$Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1").Select()
$workbook.saveas($path)
$Excel.Quit()
Remove-Variable -Name excel
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Then your only concern is that the CSV files are in the right order. If you named your CSV files Monday.csv, Tuesday.csv etc this could probably be simpler, but so long as they're named so that Monday's is the first, and it goes in alpha-numeric order you'll be just fine with that code.

(Edited to reflect comment suggestions for single cell selection before saving and changed -notin to -notcontains)

Comment: Thanks for this!  It does exactly what my goal is however there is the range of cells on each worksheet still highlighted.  I know there's an `unselect` method some place to unselect things once the worksheet gets added but it's eluding me at the moment.

Comment: Um, just add one line before saving it `$Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1").Select()` and that'll just make the first cell of the current sheet be the only thing selected.

Comment: Ran into a problem with the operator -notin because I've got Powershell v4 on my workstation and I cannot expect everyone who would be using this to have PS v4.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Swap the order and use -NotContains. `($B -notin $A)` is the same as `($A -notcontains $B)` for our purposes and is more backwards compatible. (updated answer to reflect my suggestions)

Comment: Something's off.  The XLSX sunday worksheet doesn't have the data from the Sunday.CSV and if I rename the source CSVs to `aMonday` then `bTuesday` and so on, the worksheet order is correct.

Comment: Ok, since it looks like you have your files named Monday.csv, Tuesday.csv etc I have updated the code. See if that works better for you.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply.  I'm working on a different script that eliminates the need for messing with CSV files.